# Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK

Tags: android-studio, xamarin.android, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator

I have a problem with the Android Studio, at the top there is a bar that says Gradle sync failed, and in the notes from the bottom there is this comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK. ,, and the version of Android is 3.2, and my computer is 32 bit, I updated the gradle as I watched the video from Google, but so far I have not found a solution to the problem, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following solved it:

**File->Other settings->Default Project Structure**

[image: Default Project Structure]

**Tick Mark the Use Embedded JDK (recommended)**

Then Hit Apply .

Comment: do you have set up path for jdk ?? try installing jdk saperatlly then add to user variable path , then try again

Comment: Ok, I'll try and tell you what's happening with me .. And that's the rest of the message that appears below: Gradle sync failed: Could not run JVM from the selected JDK.
        Please ensure JDK installation is valid and compatible with the current OS (Windows 10 10.0, x86).
        If you are using embedded JDK, please make sure to download Android Studio bundle compatible
        with the current OS. For example, for x86 systems please choose a 32 bits download option.

Comment: have you installed 32 bit setup on your pc? according to this message , you have installed 64-bit setup causing this error as you are using 32-bit system

Comment: Check it in project structure compiler version is selected or not

Comment: On the official website of Oracle I did not find jdk windows 32bit all i found for 64 bit, can you help me with this?